# How to setup Nginx/Apache on Oracle Cloud Instance?

Tags: nginx, vpn, cloud

My server IP is `132.145.167.69`. I have set up `Nginx` and allowed inbound/outbound traffic, still not able to open the IP in the browser or get anything in `Nginx` `access.log`.

On Server:

```
curl -I http://localhost:80
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Fri, 27 Sep 2019 14:04:05 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 612
Last-Modified: Fri, 20 Sep 2019 05:18:46 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5d846136-264"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

On My System:

```
curl -I http://132.145.167.69:80
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Server: squid/3.5.27
Mime-Version: 1.0
Date: Fri, 27 Sep 2019 14:04:37 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 3484
X-Squid-Error: ERR_CONNECT_FAIL 60
Vary: Accept-Language
Content-Language: en
X-Cache: MISS from localhost
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from localhost:3128
Via: 1.1 localhost (squid/3.5.27)
Connection: keep-alive
```

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: At most of the cloud providers, you have to port forward the public traffic. I never used Oracle Cloud, but i guess you have to do the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was with `iptables`, I had to manually add entries for the port 80 and 443.

```sh
sudo iptables -I INPUT 2 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I INPUT 2 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```